# Android Recyclerview sound with picture

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, soundcloud

I search solution for this isssue and can't find it:
- the app displays pictures in RecyclerView 
- now sound plays but only one for all items and when you exit enter the activity it skips to next sound 
- I want to play different sound for each photo clicked by the user

There is my adapter code

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

private static  MediaPlayer mySound;

private ArrayList<Article> mArticles = new ArrayList<>();
public RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

private class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public ImageView mTitle;

    public MyViewHolder(View pItem) {
        super(pItem);

        mTitle = (ImageView) pItem.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    }
}

 public MyAdapter(ArrayList<Article> pArticles, RecyclerView pRecyclerView) {
    mArticles = pArticles;
    mRecyclerView = pRecyclerView;
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, final int i) {
           View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.article_layout_allcats, viewGroup, false);

       view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
           mySound = MediaPlayer.create(v.getContext(), Article.getSounds());
          mySound.start();
        }
     });

    return new MyViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, final int i) {
    // uzupełniamy layout artykułu
    Article article = mArticles.get(i);
    ((MyViewHolder) viewHolder).mTitle.setImageResource(article.getTitle());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mArticles.size();

}
```

And

```
public class Article {
private int mTitle;
public static int mSounds;

private static int[] sTitles = {
PAWEL int[] sTitles ={
        R.drawable.photo1,
        ...
        R.drawable.photo10
};

public static int[] sSounds = { 
        R.raw.sound1, 
        ...
        R.raw.sound10

        };

public Article() {

    Random random = new Random();

   mTitle = sTitles[random.nextInt(sTitles.length)];
    mSounds = sSounds[random.nextInt(sSounds.length)];
}
public int getTitle() {
    return mTitle;

}
public static int getSounds() {
    return mSounds;

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably issue is because `setOnClickListener` is in `onCreateViewHolder`.

Use `onBindViewHolder` method to get `setOnClickListener` for whole row of `RecyclerView` :

**1.** Change   `MyViewHolder` to get root View of row:

```
public View view;
public MyViewHolder(View pItem) {
        super(pItem);

        this.view=pItem;
        ....
    }
```

**2.** Now add click listener to `view` in `onBindViewHolder` :

```
View rowView=((MyViewHolder)viewHolder).view;
rowView.setTag(article.getSounds()); // set sound it here
view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
          mySound = MediaPlayer.create(v.getContext(),
                    (Integer.parseInt(v.getTag().toString())));
          mySound.start();
        }
 });
```